# Does __getitem__() split by word or characters?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a class and within the class I had a `__getitem__()` but when I call for it to return a word in the sentence it returns the letter.

```
class Sentence():
    #initial attributes
    sentence = ""
    new_sentence = ''
    def __init__(self,new_sentence):
        self.sentence = new_sentence 
        self.word_list = new_sentence.split()# creates a word list
    def __str__(self):
        return self.sentence # return the original sentence
    def __add__(self,other):
        self.new_sentence = str(self.sentence)+ " " + str(other.sentence)
        return self.new_sentence
    def __getitem__(self,index):
        print('in getitem')
        return self.sentence[index]

def main():
    text1 = "I went home."
    text2 = "I got sleep."
    sentence1 = Sentence(text1)
    sentence2 = Sentence(text2)
    full_sentence = sentence1 + sentence2
    print(sentence1)
    print(full_sentence)
    print(sentence1[1])
```

The `print(sentence1[1])` gives me an empty space.
Also I was wondering how I can alter `__getitem__()` so that If I right `print(sentence1[0])` or `print(sentence2[1])` it will give me the word contained in the index of full_sentence.

Comment: You actually created `self.word_list`, yet you're not using it. Do you understand the code you wrote, or did someone give you part of it?

Comment: Also, side-note, your `__add__` is returning a plain `str`, not a new `Sentence`. Was that intended?

Comment: @ShadowRanger. Not to mention that it is mutating the current object as though it was `__iadd__()`

Comment: @MadPhysicist: Well, sort of. It's setting an attribute, `self.new_sentence`, that isn't actually used anywhere else (the meaningful state is in `self.sentence`). So it's technically a mutation, but not one that affects any of the methods. It's weird.

Comment: @ShadowRanger agreed :)

Comment: @ShadowRanger   I actually wrote the code but I deleted the part where I made a method returning the words in the sentence. I didn't realize it could be used to also print the index. So you said that I'm not printing a new sentence but rather just a string? The reason I added the `str()` was because I kept getting an error and it stopped occurring when I added it.

Comment: @ShadowRanger the reason I haven't used the `self.new_sentence` is because I kept getting the letter returned instead of the word from the index.  What `__getitem__` really needs to be printing is `new_sentence[index]` when asked for `sentence1[1]` it should print went and `sentence[2]` would print home. But was trying to figure out why it return just a character instead of the word when it was called.

Answer (score 0):

`split()` works based on spaces (words). However, you are not accessing its result: Your `__getitem__()` method returns `self.sentence[index]`. `sentence` is a string, so you are returning a character from a string. I think you meant to do `return self.word_list[index]` in `__getitem__()`.

To answer the question in the title: `__getitem__()` does not split anything. It normally just accessed whatever you tell it to.